# how to get last column value of respective row of excel sheet in java using Apache POI

Tags: java, servlets, apache-poi

i have following excel sheet

```
id     JobId     Name      Dept        Add       Salary
101      41      Bob     Editing    New York     $ 5000
```

i am passing id,jobid as request parameter to servlet from $.ajax() method. i want to get salary cell data of excel sheet by matching request parameters i.e id and jobid with excel sheet contents and insert it other table. How to do this?

here is my code...

```
   FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(fileToBeRead);
   workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
   int jobid = Integer.ParseInt(request.getParameter("jobid"));

          if (id == 101) {
             // get first sheet 
               HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
               Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
               statement = conn.createStatement() ;
               ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("Select job_id,Job,Name, Deptname from Emp,Department where Department.job_id=" + jobid + " AND Emp.Id=" + id + " ");

                while (resultset.next()) { 

                   //how to match database result with excel records and save to other table



                }//resultset.next() ends here...

            resultset.close();
        }
```

i try to do like this......? for e.g but it gives error 
i am trying to match id=101 and Add=New York for e.g and want to get salary data.
if use **if(data[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("101"))** condition it works but i want to match both id and Address i.e. **if(data[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("101") && data[i][j+5].equalsIgnoreCase("New York"))** it gives error

```
    int rowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
    int colNum = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    String[][] data = new String[rowNum][colNum];
   // System.out.println("Row No :"+rowNum +" \nCol no:"+colNum);

    for (int i = 1; i < rowNum; i++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
            String value = null;
            double price;
           // int type = cell.getCellType();

            value = cell.getStringCellValue();

                    data[i][j] = value;
                    if(data[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("101") && data[i][j+4].equalsIgnoreCase("New York"))
                        {
                            Cell lastCellInRow = row.getCell(row.getLastCellNum() - 1);
                            System.out.println(lastCellInRow.getStringCellValue());

                    }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're simply trying to get access to the last cell in a row, and you have a [`Row`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html), try the following:

```
Cell lastCellInRow = row.getCell(row.getLastCellNum() - 1); // -1 because #s are 0-based
```

**EDIT** To address your updated question and the comments below.
This code should do what you're looking for without going through the rigmarole of converting the entire spreadsheet into a 2D array, which is frankly terribly inefficient when you have access to all the data right at your fingertips.

```
for (int i = 1; i < rowNum; i++) {
  Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
  Cell cell1 = row.getCell(0);
  Cell cell2 = row.getCell(4);
  String id = cell1.getStringCellValue();
  String city = cell2.getStringCellValue();

  if(id.equalsIgnoreCase("101") && city.equalsIgnoreCase("New York")) {
    Cell lastCellInRow = row.getCell(row.getLastCellNum() - 1);
    System.out.println(lastCellInRow.getStringCellValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion, but i having prob i have mentioned it in my editted questions :)

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: i understand i need to use data[i][j]==101 and cell.getStringNumericvalue(); but i have replaced 101 to F101 in excel for convinience....

Comment: Well of course you're gonna get a NPE - `data[i][j+4]` is not initialized at the time you're trying to access it.  If you really want to use the 2D String array solution, you're going to have to parse the whole spreadsheet into the string array before doing any processing on it.  Alternatively, try the edit in my answer above